# unable to upload image when run my code in github actions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I need to upload an image using selenium webdriver and run it **locally** and on **GitHub actions** using java language :

1. I added the image in the folder in my project
2. get absolute path to my image
3. used sendKeys() to send the absolute path of my image
4. when running code locally works fine but when running it on **GitHub Action** returns an error "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException:"

   ```
   File file = new File("src/main/resources/UploadImage/MyImage.png");
   imageUploadChooseFile.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
   ```

Screenshot for the error :
[Screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07LFO.png)

Comment: It would be useful to post the full error message.

Comment: And also the YAML. Please see here on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask